# Сортировка списка в котором есть str и int

Tags: python, list

Нужно отсортировать список Z-A

```
my_list = ['Reznikov', 'Kiev', 'programmer', 30]
```

Буду благодарен за помощь. Понимаю что нужно использовать `.sort` или `.sorted` но еще нуб, что то делаю не так.

Comment: `>>> sorted(map(str, my_list))
['30', 'Kiev', 'Reznikov', 'programmer']`

Comment: `Z-A` это в смысле в обратном порядке?

Comment: Я так понимаю, да. В любом случае так интереснее

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обратной сортировки задавайте параметр `reverse=True`, а т.к. в списке есть и числа и строки, то при сортировке нужно к одному виду их приводить, к строке через параметр `key=str`.

Исходный список:

```
my_list = ['Reznikov', 'Kiev', 'programmer', 30]
print(my_list)  # ['Reznikov', 'Kiev', 'programmer', 30]
```

Для сортировки с изменением текущего списка, используйте [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort):

```
my_list.sort(key=str, reverse=True)
print(my_list)  # ['programmer', 'Reznikov', 'Kiev', 30]
```

Если исходный список менять не желательно, тогда поможет функция [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted), которая вернет новый список:

```
my_list2 = sorted(my_list, key=str, reverse=True)
print(my_list2)  # ['programmer', 'Reznikov', 'Kiev', 30]
```

---

В тех случаях, когда на основе своего списка **нужно создать новый**, применив к каждому его элементу функцию, а после отсортировать это:

```
# Используя генератор списка
print(sorted([str(item) for item in my_list], reverse=True))

# Функциональный стиль: map вызывает функцию str для каждого элемента my_list
print(sorted(map(str, my_list), reverse=True))
```

Comment: Спс. То что я и хотел

Comment: Ответ некорректен, так как меняется исходный массив. По хорошему, нужно использовать `sorted(my_list, key=str)`

Comment: @YaroslavSurzhikov, вы правы

Answer (score 0):

Более интересен вопрос корректной сортировки `str` содержащих цифры.
Например, сортировка 
`slist = ['x1_name', 'x10_name', 'x2_name', 'x110_name']`

Обычный `sorted(slist)` даст сортировку в неверном порядке
`['x10_name', 'x110_name', 'x1_name', 'x2_name']`

Чтобы отсортировать правильно, нужно преобразовывать цифры в `int` и возращать строки в виде `list`: `'x1_name'` -> `['x', 1, '_name']`

```
import re
def numerical_sort(value: str) -> list:
    parts = re.compile(r'(\d+)').split(value)
    parts[1::2] = map(int, parts[1::2])
    return parts

sorted(slist, key=numerical_sort)
```

`['x1_name', 'x2_name', 'x10_name', 'x110_name']`

Comment: Я тут как раз нашел интересный модуль, что подходит под такую задачу (natsorted). Советую ознакомится. http://pythonhosted.org/natsort/intro.html